# How to fix allowed memory size exhausted in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.6 in windows 10. The database that I used is MySQL 8.0 . When i try to load web view from my browser, memory size exhausted error message occur in laravel log and does show anything in web view.

[Wed Dec 26 09:34:47 2018] PHP Fatal error:

> Allowed memory size of 2097152 byte s exhausted (tried to allocate
>   4096 bytes) in D:\Project\Project-Serve\ven
>   dor\composer\autoload_static.php on line 168

Comment: Without knowing what code generated this it's anyone's guess as to what went wrong. Are you loading a page that has a very, very, very long list of records?

Comment: i use laravel 5.6 and there are few record in db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Increase the memory_limit in php.ini file.**

To know which php.ini is loading. use following command

> php -i | grep "php.ini"

Restart web server.

Answer (score 6):

Look up "etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini" this directory. 
In the php.ini file change this:

```
; Old one
; memory_limit = 2048M

; New one
; memory_limit = 4096M
```